# did i mistype something because it keep coming up with - Undefined variable '__main__'

Tags: python, tkinter, visual-studio-code

this is a code to create a login i am followinng tutorial but it gave me the error in the title

from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
from  tkinter import ttk
import random
import time
import datetime

```
def main ():
    root = Tk()
    app = Window1(root)


class Window1:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("login screen")
        self.master.geometry('1350x750+0+0')
        self.master.config(bg = 'powder blue')
        self.frame = Frame(self.master, bg = 'powder blue')
        self.frame.pack()


    def new_window(self):
        self.newWindow= Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Window2(self.newWindow)

class Window2:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Overview")
        self.master.geometry('1350x750+0+0')
        self.master.config(bg = 'cadet blue')
        self.frame = Frame(self.master, bg = 'cadet blue')
        self.frame.pack()




if __main__ == 'main__':
    main()
```

Comment: i am new to python so thats why i am nt very good at coding

Comment: You mean `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Comment: thank you it fixed now but for some reason in visual studio code it doesnt run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `__main__` has to be imported. Anyway, i believe, what you actually need is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```